# No such file to load when requiring jruby pg on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundle, jruby, pg

I'm looking to use the jRuby pg gem in a jRuby application. The gem runs fine locally, but when run on heroku it is unable to load the pg gem.

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- pg
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
  require at /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3-jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
   (root) at text.rb:19
```

My Gemfile is:

```
ruby '1.9.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '1.7.19'
gem 'pg', '0.17.1', :platform => :jruby, :git => 'git://github.com/headius/jruby-pg.git', :branch => :master
```

Heroku `bundle show` returns:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
 * pg (0.17.1 c236a38)
```

Heroku `ruby -v` returns:

```
jruby 1.7.19 (1.9.3p551) 2015-02-06 fffffff on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_60-cedar14-b24 +jit [linux-amd64]
```

text.rb contains:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
puts "cool!"
```

So far I have:

- run bundle locally and repushed
- run bundle install locally and repushed
- cleared Gemfile.lock repushed and then run bundle on heroku
- updated heroku toolbelt
- updated ruby gems
- checked to see that I'm running the same version of jruby locally and on heroku
- uninstalled pg gem and reinstalled
- required rubygems in the text.rb file
- required the absolute path of pg.rb on heroku, this resulted in an unable to load pg_ext error

Comment: This was pretty easy to reproduce ([jruby-pg-test](https://github.com/jkutner/jruby-pg-test)) but i don't know what's going on. running `$ heroku run ls vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems` shows that it's not there. It could be an related to the projects lack of a gemspec.

Comment: Have you tried [activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter)? This is what most production deployments use in place of `pg`.

Comment: @codefinger from http://bundler.io/git.html "If there is no .gemspec at the root of a git repository, you must specify a version that bundler should use when resolving dependencies" Based on this my understanding is that my current require is ok without the gemspec.

Comment: @codefinger thanks for looking into this with me.. I have also seen this used, however, am not keen on using ActiveRecord as the pg gem should be able to be run standalone... it also works fine locally

Comment: I take it back. The gem is under `$ heroku run ls ls vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/bundler/gems`. Still not sure why it's not picked up. activerecord is definitely the on the happy path. I'm not sure how well jruby-pg is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, you'll need to prefix your `Procfile` command with `bundle exec` (because it's a non-standard gem Heroku can't put it on the path automatically).

For example:

```
test: bundle exec ruby text.rb
```

However, this will add a bit of overhead to your JRuby startup time because Bundler has to launch two JRuby processes (one for itself, and then another with the correct gem context).

Another option is to use the [activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter), which is more widely adopted.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you very much for the help! For others here is an explanation as to why bundle exec is required.

From bundler.io: In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle. 
However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain. Even if it looks like it works, it may not work in the future or on another machine.